# Datetime issues while sending and receiving through json

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, json

I'm getting this date and time while selecting DateTime picker from angular 
"Thu Jan 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)" 
actual date-time in my system is 10 Jan 2019 9.51

while am receiving data in asp.net api, I get a date like this.
{09/01/2019 8:00:00 PM}

### angular.

```
    export interface sample{
        vr_date: Date
    }

`this.adapter.setLocale('en-GB');` // i use this to get date format in dd/mm/yyyy format
```

---

### asp api

```
public class sample
{

        public Nullable<System.DateTime> vr_date{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date to string before converting to JSON.

use-

```
var date=dateObject.toLocaleDateString();
```

then send the date via JSON.